# How can I get the full response from a TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge?

Tags: delphi, indy, idhttp

I need to store the response of a request in my webservice. I can capture the request this way:

```
procedure TMyIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.DoCommandGet(AThread: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  MyLog.ResquetInfo := ARequestInfo.PostStream; 

  //When I try this I get an access violation
  MyLog.ResponseInfo := AResponseInfo.ContentStream;
end;
```

Does there exist any other event where I can capture the full response?

Comment: You are responsible for providing your own `ContentStream` for the requested data, that is why your code is crashing when trying to use `ContentStream` before it has been assigned anything. If you want to capture the raw data being sent back and forth, you can assign an intercept component to the  `AContext.Connection.Intercept` property, such as one of the `TIdLog... ` components.

Comment: Hi Remy! Thanks for your reply. It works! You are the best... Thanks!